# wordpress wp_query get post from the n-th

Tags: php, wordpress

in my blog I have done a sidebar where are displayed some articles. It is done by querying wordpress:

```
            $pq = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => $ptype, 'showposts' => $pshow ));
```

My question is: how can I get retrieve articles from the 6-th, and not from the last posted?
Thank you so much.

In alternative, how can I extract random post different from the last six post?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `'offset' => n` to your query to bounce over the first n results.